# Did the Kayı tribe fight the Templars at any point?

Tags: ottoman-empire, turkey, templars

The highly popular Turkish TV drama series [Diriliş: Ertuğrul](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirili%C5%9F:_Ertu%C4%9Frul) has Ertuğrul and his [Kayı tribe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kay%C4%B1_(tribe)) fighting the Templars based in a "castle" which apparently should be identified with the real-world [Bagras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bagras).

Thing is: the Templars were only active in what is in modern terms south and south-eastern Turkey (according to [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Knights_Templar_sites)) while the Kayı and their successor Ottomans lived and fought in northwestern Turkey.

Am I missing some connection here or is the whole plot just pure artistic license?

Comment: What I found with some quick digging is that the makeup (and even size) of armies at the time isn't very strongly known, so this is the kind of question that will end up either be answered "Yes" (assuming someone finds a battle they were recorded participating in), or "Quite possibly, but we don't know."

Comment: Unlikely, as far as I know Templars did not operate so close to modern Turkey (it was Byzantine Empire then) . Whole TV show is one of recent Neo-Ottoman propaganda works, which are increasingly popular under Erdogan, so take everything with substantial grain of salt.

Comment: If Bagras is where wiki says (the southernmost point of turkey on Syrian coast), it is well within the crusader states area (principality of Antioch) - even in your cited wiki you can see that.  About northeastern turkey, close to the black sea, note that medieval Georgians had symbols similar to the crusaders - look to the current flag of Georgia, it comes from medieval times. Maybe it is just a confusion of markings, flags, shields, etc.

Comment: @Luiz I only watched a handful of episodes but it was very clearly about Templars. As for Bagras, I picked that up as a possible identification of the "castle" on the web. The question remains: how could the Kayi fight the Templars when they were presumably so far away from each other?

Comment: I do not know. But I would edit the question to state that the show tells explicitly they were Templars, not just some christian guys with markings similar to them. And it would help if you have some other clue about where Bagras really should be.